# UFT 14.x cannot execute ctrlC+ctrlV in IE

Tags: vbscript, scripting, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I need a solution for this error
Before using UFT 14.x , I wrote my code on UFT 12 (on windows 7) for copy/paste function. (It worked 100%)
When I upgraded UFT to 14.x , that function respond with an error . The code and the image are the following :

```
Function WritingFast(strDataTable)


  set objCB=createobject("Mercury.Clipboard")
  objCD.Clear()
  objCD.SetText (strDataTable)
  Window("Internet Explorer").WinObject("Internet Explorer_Server").Type micCtrlDwn + "v" +micCtrlUp
  objCB.GetText


End Function
```

[image: Error]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `WinObject("Internet Explorer_Server")` is not unique, what are you trying to refer to by this object?

Please examine the description of the object in the object repository in order to see why the description there isn't enough to make it unique.

Alternatively you could take a step back and think about what you're trying to do, perhaps UFT's web support allows you to do it directly and not by trying to access the underlying Win32 objects.

Comment: I edited my post with the image about that object. 
The description properties is the same as the description that I used in the 12.02 version.
Then in the object repository there are no duplicate . It's the first time that I have an error like this .
To answer your question , the refer is the entire page of the web application (without IE toolbar etc..)

Comment: Has the version of IE  changed?

Comment: Yes . 
I had win 7 with a IE version ( don't remember which is) . Now i have win 10 with the latest version.

Comment: In my opinion this is most likely the cause, not the different versions of UFT (not that this helps you...)

Comment: Well, I tried to re-spy that object but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment, rules, sorry. Gonna put has an answer but its more a tip.

If you don't have a duplicate, try capture the object again. See if UFT recognize that object exists or not at your repository.

At least you can see what he is capturing whit the upgrade and compare (if different).

Comment: I already tried but nothing works . 
The only things that is different from the 12.02 script to 14.x is the IE version . ( I had to upgrade the machine from win 7)

Comment: hum...So i will assume that are the same objects whit the same proprieties. You don't have more then one browser open don't you? lol anyway try whit another version of IE if you have the change.

Comment: I tried with the oldest and the latest version actually used in windows 10, but nothing works

Comment: Can be a problem of the IE itself. Try another browser see what you get.

Comment: It's hard, it seems that creating a script in IE makes it not working in Chrome/another browser . So it's not that simple even because the object " internet explorer_server " doesn't exists in chrome

Comment: Oh my mistake, forgot the "internet explorer_server" . Well i'm out of suggestions. Someone whit more expertise have to help you. I would keep a ticket open at support, so they can help.